# Double braces in equation

Tags: equations, braces

I'm trying to create the formulae shown below. But I don't know how to get the double braces to work.

[image: The desired formulae]

This is my attempt with only single brace:

```
    x(t_n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
  0      &\quad \mbox{ $n<ns$ or $n>ne$} \\
  x(t_n) &\quad \mbox{ $ns\leq n\leq ne$}
\end{array} \right.
```

Could someone help me with the second brace? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is easier to do with the cases environment than with array.  Where did the image come from?

Comment: I did the image in equation editor in MS Word.

Comment: @Dan That image is broken. I have replaced it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try `cases` in `amsmath`.

```
 \begin{equation}
    x(t_n) = \begin{cases}
        0 \\
        x(t_n) 
    \end{cases}
    \xi(t_n) = \begin{cases}
        0      &n<ns, n>ne \\
        \xi(t_n) &ns\leq n\leq ne$
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This didn't give the middle part of the image.

Comment: @Dan -- Oh, I just gave the `cases` example and thought you could do the rest. Sorry. I added the whole solution.

Comment: @RichardHerron There's an extra `$`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{minimal} \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ x(t_n) =\begin{cases} 0\\x(t_n)  \end{cases}\quad
\xi(t_n)=\begin{cases} 0 & \qquad\qquad (n<ns, n>ne) \\
\xi(t_n) & \qquad\qquad (n\leq n\leq ne) 
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```